# SoundCloud API : I can't decode Json data

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, curl, soundcloud

I have an issue with SounCloud PHP wrapper. When I make an oembed request to the SounCloud API. This last one gives me back a string data. It's composed by something like a header and the JSON data. It looks like this:

```
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: MISS
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{"version":1.0,"type":"rich",......."author_url":"https://soundcloud.com/forss"}
```

So when I use `json_decode` function on this data it can't decode the JSON part.
Does anyone have any idea in how do delete header from this content?

NB: I am working behind an proxy so I have add this code below to make the curl request work

```
$client->setCurlOptions(array(
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_PROXY => "http://xxxxxxxxxx",
        CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => 8080,
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "xxxx:xxxx",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange! what you can do is:

```
if(strstr($response, "{") !== false){
    $response = substr($response, strstr("{"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

I' ve set CURLOPT_HEADER to false and add fix some lines on the soundcloud php wrapper:

    if(array_key_exists(CURLOPT_HEADER, $options) && !$options[CURLOPT_HEADER])
     $this->_lastHttpResponseBody = $data;
    else
        $this->_lastHttpResponseBody = substr($data, $info['header_size']);